# defmulti vs defprotocol?

Tags: clojure, protocols, records, clojure-1.3

It seems like both can be used to define functions that you can implement later, with different data types. AFAIK the major difference is that `defmulti` works on maps and `defprotocol` works on records.

What other differences there? What are the benefits of using one over the other?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short version: `defmulti` is much more flexible and general, while `defprotocol` performs better.

Slightly longer version:

`defprotocol` supports dispatch on type, which is like polymorphism in most mainstream programming languages.

`defmulti` is a more general mechanism where you can dispatch on other things than just a single type. This flexibility comes with a performance penalty.

[More on protocols](http://clojure.org/protocols)

[More on multimethods](http://clojure.org/multimethods)

Comment: Aha, thank you! It also seems that the functions don't need to be declared together, like `extend-type` requires. Is this correct?

Comment: You can think of a protocol as a Java interface. So with `defprotocol` you need to declare the functions together. A multimethod declaration is a single thing, but the `defmethod` definitions don't have to be together.

Answer (score 5):

Just an addition to cover the motivation, corvuscorax's answer covers the origional question nicely.

Originally Clojure only had **multimethods** and very early on a lot of thought went into building a dispatch **abstraction that could handle all cases** very well and would not force people to structure their abstractions around a limitation of the abstractions offered by the language.

As Clojure matured the desire to create "clojure in clojure" required abstractions that where at least in theory capable of producing any bytecode that could be produced by java and thus the need for **protocols**, a dispatch abstraction that **more closely matched native Java.**
Clojure has a strong "embrace your platform" ideal and protocols suit this mindset very well.

Comment: I see. So what is the benefit of writing Clojure in Clojure?

Comment: One reason is to be able to write Clojure at a higher level of abstraction. Kind of like writing a C compiler in C, instead of in assembly. This would also make things like ClojureScript easier to do, and make it easier to keep the CLR port of Clojure in sync with the JVM version. Plus, it's cool and elegant in a Gödel, Escher, Bach-ish way :-)